# Will every human being be resurrected?

Tags: authenticity, day-of-judgement, soul

Assalamu alaykum. I have pondering for some time over an ayah in the Quran where Allah swt tells us that every soul will come on the Day of Judgement. I wonder, does this mean that the terms 'soul' and 'human' are interchangeable in this context. Does this mean that every human being is born with a soul, and thus, everyone will come on the Day of Judgement with no exceptions?
Jazakallahu Khayran.

Comment: Yes, exactly, you're right.

Comment: Even the jinns will come. No exceptions. Basically the Earth is going to be destroyed (i think by the sun)

Answer (score 1):

و عليكم السلام والرحمة الله وبركاته

Soul is part of unseen and we have very little knowledge about it.

> And they ask you, [O Muhammad], about the **soul**. Say, "The **soul
> is of the affair of my Lord**. And mankind have not been given of
> knowledge except a little." Quran 17:85

What we know is human being consists of a **soul** and a **body** together. The soul is an entity which differs from the physical body. When we die soul exits our body and enters into a different dimension. Just like how the soul exits during our sleep.

> “Allâh takes soul at the time of their death **and [the souls] of those
> that do not die during their sleep.** He retains those souls for which
> He has ordained death, whereas He releases the rest for an appointed
> term.” Quran 39:42

During resurrection every soul will be joined with its physical body for accounting. Because the deeds were committed by both body and soul on earth. To answer your question, Yes, all human beings will be resurrected to receive reward or punishment.